# Plugin for jQuery AJAX "live" searching

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI. I followed the [Search, Sort, Paginate with AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) RailsCast and at the end of that Ryan Bates say:

> "in *production mode* you should improve the live search with some
>   plugin"

What jQuery plugin do you advice to implement an AJAX live search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any You want from [this selection](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-search-scripts/) for example.

I personally have used [this one](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/twitter-like-search-with-jquery-ajax.html) without problem.